# Angular 4 CLI cannot find name 'jasmine'

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I am using the Angular 4 CLI (v.1.0.0) and to handle testing I created some mocks that use jasmine to create a spy. In the IDE everything looks okay, however in the terminal I am getting and error that says "Cannot find name 'jasmine'".

At first I thought the issue was that jasmine wasn't added to the typings but I can see that package.json includes the import for the jasmine type def so I'm not sure what is missing.

mocks.ts

```
export class MockAuthService {
  public login: Function = jasmine.createSpy('login');
}

export class MockHttpService {
  public delete: Function = jasmine.createSpy('delete');
  public get: Function = jasmine.createSpy('get');
  public post: Function = jasmine.createSpy('post');
  public put: Function = jasmine.createSpy('put');
}
```

running ng serve returns the following error messages in the terminal.

> ERROR in C:/Users/efarley/Desktop/repos/prod/src/app/mocks/mocks.ts
>   (2,23): Cannot find name 'jasmine'.
>   C:/Users/efarley/Desktop/repos/prod/src/app/mocks/mocks.ts (6,24):
>   Cannot find name 'jasmine'.
>   C:/Users/efarley/Desktop/repos/prod/src/app/mocks/mocks.ts (7,21):
>   Cannot find name 'jasmine'.
>   C:/Users/efarley/Desktop/repos/prod/src/app/mocks/mocks.ts (8,22):
>   Cannot find name 'jasmine'.
>   C:/Users/efarley/Desktop/repos/prod/src/app/mocks/mocks.ts (9,21):
>   Cannot find name 'jasmine'.
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "prod",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of the cli are you using? also, can you post all your `tsconfig` files (if you have many). if you are on angular-cli `v1.0.0` you should see `"types": [ "jasmine", ...]` in the file `src/tsconfig.spec.json`

Comment: I am running angular-cli v1.0.0. I don't see a `types` key in the tsconfig.json but I see a `typeRoots`. I've updated the question to include the config file.

Comment: do you not have `src/tsconfig.spec.json` ?

Comment: Ah yes, adding it to the question now.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are getting the error because TypeScript is trying to include the mock in the `app` build, and the app (rightly) doesn't know about Jasmine.

Exclude the mock from your app compilation by adding it to the `exclude` array in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works fine for `ng serve` but it doesn't seem to have any effect, when running `ng build`. I use Angular CLI 1.6.7. Any advice?

Comment: Ok, I could solve this, too. I still had an import in DevModule that imported my mocks. I split up DevModule and TestModule now to make sure not lo load TestModule during `ng build`.

Answer (score 4):

> I am not sure if you should be creating jasmine spys that way, but regardless:

The issue is with your file name

notice: `tsconfig.spec.json` has: `"include": ["**/*.spec.ts","**/*.d.ts"]`

and your file name is `mocks.ts`.

either change the file name to `mocks.spec.ts`

or add `"**/*.mock.ts"` and rename to something like `service.mock.ts`

Hope this helps.

Comment: mocks.spec.ts worked. Good find. I'm curious why you question creating spys this way though. The idea is that I can create mock services that I pass to the unit tests to use with every method already spied upon so there is no need to declare spys in a test spec. If I need to modify the return value I can easily do that in the test where needed. I feel it makes it quicker to write tests this way. I'd be interested in reading anything you've found that suggests another way to set up mock services.

Comment: I question because I haven't seen it done this way, if is a good practice and works for your use-case, no problem. Glad I can help :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me and then I realised the problem was:

the ignored file was still included in an `index.ts` which was then imported by my app, so even if the `tsconfig.conf` was ignoring it, it would still end up included.